# Xamarin Renderer does not respond to changed property

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have some problem with a custom renderer. My sample is based on a sample from the official Xamarin site but I can't get the OnElementPropertyChanged method in the renderer is not triggered when I add an Item to the bound list.

Cell:

```
public class NativeiOSListViewCell : UITableViewCell
{

    UILabel name;

    public NativeiOSListViewCell(NSString cellId) : base(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellId)
    {
        SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Gray;
        ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(218, 255, 127);
        name = new UILabel()
        {
            Font = UIFont.FromName("Cochin-BoldItalic", 22f),
            TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(127, 51, 0),
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear
        };
        ContentView.Add(name);
    }

    public void UpdateCell(string caption)
    {
        name.Text = caption;

    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();
        name.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(5, 4, ContentView.Bounds.Width - 63, 25);

    }

}
```

Renderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyNativeListView), typeof(Blabla.iOS.NativeiOSListViewRenderer))]
namespace Blabla.iOS
{
    public class NativeiOSListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                // Unsubscribe
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Control.Source = new NativeiOSListViewSource(e.NewElement as MyNativeListView);
            }
        }


        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == MyNativeListView.ItemsProperty.PropertyName) //Only triggered for stuff like Height, Width and not Items
            {
                Control.Source = new NativeiOSListViewSource(Element as MyNativeListView);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Blabla.PlayGroundPage" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Blabla;assembly=Blabla">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:Inverter x:Key="inverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <local:MyNativeListView x:Name="nativeListView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Items="{Binding LocalItems}" />
            <Button Text="add" Command="{Binding Add}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class PlayGroundPage : ContentPage
{
    public PlayGroundPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PlayGroundViewModel viewModel = new PlayGroundViewModel();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class PlayGroundViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand Add { get; private set; }
    private ObservableCollection<ListItem> _localItems;
    public ObservableCollection<ListItem> LocalItems { get { return _localItems; } set { _localItems = value; SetChangedProperty("LocalItems"); } }
    public PlayGroundViewModel()
    {
        Add = new Command(() => { AddItem(); });
        LocalItems = new ObservableCollection<ListItem>();

    }
    private void AddItem()
    {
        ListItem item = new ListItem("a", "b", true); //Just to get something to pop up in the list.
        LocalItems.Add(item);
        SetChangedProperty("LocalItems");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void SetChangedProperty(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

}
```

ListItem

```
public class ListItem
{

    public string SelectedType { get; set; }
    public string SelectedOption { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

    public ListItem(string selectedType, string selectedOption, bool isChecked)
    {
        SelectedType = selectedType;
        SelectedOption = selectedOption;
        IsChecked = isChecked;
    }
}
```

I have verified that SetChangedProperty is triggered, but nothing seems to happen after that. I would appreciate if anyone has a clue to why.

Answer (score 2):

The `PropertyChanged` event is triggered when the property really has changed. Your list doesn't change, only its contents, so the property with the list itself still refers to the same object (the list).

You're using an `ObservableCollection`, which is the way to go. The thing is that you have to subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event in your renderer.

Also, it might be easier to use the default `ListView` and just create a custom renderer for the cells.